# What causes vertices to become randomly linked OR form 3d shape instead of plane? (2.8 may build)

Tags: mesh, vertices, error

Whenever I create new mesh plane I usually delete it and then manually create custom shaped mesh via **ctrl+click**, then click select all vertices (**A**) and make new face from them (**F**).

However sometimes these things happen:

1. after making a new face I enter sculpting mode to find out that some of vertices have become linked ***randomly*** e.g. one point might be in the middle of the mesh and the other near the edge or few vertices away, so moving one of them causes changes to BOTH. Sometimes there are plenty of linked vertices on one single newly created mesh.
2. Also sometimes after new face was created instead of custom shaped 2d flat plane I get 3d object **with flipped normals (!)** as if all outer vertices were selected and a new face was added to form 3d object.

Why that happens? I do similar routine every time yet results always vary. Are there any hidden hotkeys I might accidently press that might cayse that? Also why for each 3d object I create that way normal are flipped?

Comment: if you create a face with more than 4 vertices you are creating a ngon. Ngons don't subdivide nicely.

Comment: normal of face is determined by the order of the vertices (the order in which vertices are referenced by the face). Clockwise and anticlockwise will give opposing normals.